# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundx on LinkedList.toArray()

Tags: java, android, linked-list

I'm working with a android game and I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run this code:

```
public RemoteVariable[] getRemoteVariable(){
    RemoteVariable[] variables = remoteQueue.toArray(new RemoteVariable[0]);
    remoteQueue.clear();
    return variables;
}
```

From what I have read on the LinkedList documentation the toArray(T[] a) method should return an array equal in size to remoteQue. In my head, that means that if remoteQue is empty then the returned array should be empty as well. I don't understand where the exeption comes from.

I have as well tired to run getRemoteVariable only if remoteQue is not empty, that didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

ON EDIT:
This is my remoteQueue class:

```
    package com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.gameecs.events;
import com.badlogic.ashley.signals.Listener;
import com.badlogic.ashley.signals.Signal;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class RemoteQueue implements Listener<RemoteVariable>{
    private LinkedList<RemoteVariable> remoteQueue;

    public RemoteQueue(){
        remoteQueue = new LinkedList<RemoteVariable>();
    }
public RemoteVariable[] getRemoteVariable(){
    RemoteVariable[] variables = remoteQueue.toArray(new RemoteVariable[0]);
    remoteQueue.clear();
    return variables;
}

public RemoteVariable poll(){
    return remoteQueue.poll();
}

@Override
public void receive(Signal<RemoteVariable> signal, RemoteVariable variable){
    remoteQueue.add(variable);
}
```

}

This is remoteVariable class

```
  package com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.gameecs.events;

public class RemoteVariable {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private String playerID;
    public RemoteVariable(float x, float y, String playerID){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.playerID=playerID;

    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String getPlayerID() {
        return playerID;
    }
}
```

And this is where getRemoteVariable is called:

```
for(RemoteVariable variable : remoteQueue.getRemoteVariable()){
        updatePosition(variable);
    }
```

This is the stack trace of exception:

```
04-12 10:16:10.112 13841-14099/com.tdt4240.jankenmaze E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1588
Process: com.tdt4240.jankenmaze, PID: 13841
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=196; index=196
    at java.util.LinkedList.toArray(LinkedList.java:958)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.gameecs.events.RemoteQueue.getRemoteVariable(RemoteQueue.java:17)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.gameecs.systems.PositionReceiveSystem.update(PositionReceiveSystem.java:35)
    at com.badlogic.ashley.core.Engine.update(Engine.java:314)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.gameecs.EntityManager.update(EntityManager.java:128)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.states.PlayState.update(PlayState.java:67)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.states.MultiPlayState.update(MultiPlayState.java:63)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.states.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:42)
    at com.tdt4240.jankenmaze.JankenMaze.render(JankenMaze.java:71)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:495)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

Comment: How is your `remoteQueue` constructed? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @khelwood I edited my post. Is it better now?

Comment: I think the use of `.toArray()` method is wrong

Comment: Could you elaborate? From what I have seen on tutorialspoint and javadocs it is possible to use it this way.
E.g

`      Object[] array = list.toArray(new Object[4]);`

from [here ](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/linkedlist_array.htm)

Comment: Your use of `.toArray()` looks correct. Could you post the stack trace of your exception please?

Comment: Edited the main post now.
@khelwood

Comment: The only way I can see for that to happen if is the variable in `LinkedList` that tracks the size is inconsistent with the number of links actually in the list. I don't know how that would have happened. Sorry.

Comment: The problem could be multiple threads which are modifying the linkedlist. You have to synchronize these accesses then.

Comment: @beeb That makes sense, as we are using Google Play Game Services for P2P. The new problem is then that a lot of the threading is happening in the "background" so bugfixing would involve a lot of digging. Anyway, thanks for help, and any help with threading is appriciated.